# Не передаются данные из php json в ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-form

Есть форма

```
<form class="formBorder" method="POST" id="form" action="" novalidate>

<div class="form-group">
    <h3>Register</h3>
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
           placeholder="Enter email" required>
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password"
           placeholder="Password(at least 6 characters)" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control" id="password2" placeholder="Confirm the password"
           required>
</div>
<div class="form__group">
    <button type="submit" name="do_register" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</div>
```

register_controller.php обрабатывает ее и создает json при удачной валидации формы и при ошибке

```
if (isset($_POST['do_register'])) {

$errors = array();
$arrayFields = array(
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'password' => $_POST['password'],
    'password2' => $_POST['password2']
);

foreach ($arrayFields as $fieldName => $oneField) {
    if ($oneField == '' || !isset($oneField)) {
        $errors[$fieldName] = 'Required field';
    }
}

if (!filter_var($arrayFields['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    $errors['email'] = 'Email is incorrect';

if (iconv_strlen($arrayFields['name']) < 4)
    $errors['name'] = 'Name must be more than 4 characters';

if (iconv_strlen($arrayFields['password']) < 6) {

    $errors['password'] = 'Password must be more than 6 characters';
} else
    if ($arrayFields['password'] != $arrayFields['password2'])
        $errors['password2'] = 'Passwords do not match';

if (empty($errors)) {

    $array = array('result' => 'success');
    echo json_encode($array);
} else {

    $array = array('result' => 'error', 'text_error' => $errors);
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

register_form.js приимает json и форму и в зависимости от json выводит ошибку или сообщение об success

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#form').submit(function(){
    // убираем класс ошибок с инпутов
    $('input').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('error_input');
    });
    // прячем текст ошибок
    $('.error').hide();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../profile/controllers/register_controller.php",
        dataType: "json",
        // действие, при ответе с сервера
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

            if(data.result == 'success'){
                console.log(data.result);
                alert('User successfully registered');
            } else {
                for(var errorField in data.text_error){
                    // выводим текст ошибок
                    $('#'+errorField+'_error').html(data.text_error[errorField]);
                    console.log('sdsdsdsddsdsdsdsdsds');
                    // показываем текст ошибок
                    $('#'+errorField+'_error').show();
                    // обводим инпуты красным цветом
                    $('#'+errorField).addClass('error_input');
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('23435345s');

            console.log(data)
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Но json просто выводится на экран, ajax его не принимает, попадает в error

(data - {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …})

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать абсолютный путь в свойстве url. Также добавьте данные в аякс-запрос.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "абсолютный путь к register_controller.php", //абсолютный путь
    dataType: "json",
    data: $('#form').serialize(), //данные формы
    ...
```